# React-navigation swipe back moves to previous stack navigator instead of previous screen in current stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**Setup**: I have 3 stack navigators and one of them is like main application and both others are used inside it. from home navigator I navigate to insurance navigator.  and from this navigator user is able to go into multiple screens in stack as shown in the code below.

**Problem**: when navigating back if i swipe from my iphone twice or thrice in a single go it automatically navigates me back to home navigator instead of going through all the stacks. if I do swipes slowly it works fine.

**versions**:

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.1",
```

**Reference Code**:

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
  initialRouteName={'Insurance'}
>
  <Stack.Screen name="Insurance" component={InsuranceContainer} />
  <Stack.Group>
    <Stack.Screen name="FirstContainer" component={FirstContainer} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SecondContainer" component={SecondContainer} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ThirdContainer" component={ThirdContainer} />
    <Stack.Screen name="FourthContainer" component={FourthContainer} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Fifth" component={Fifth} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Sixth"
      component={Sixth}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Seventh"
      component={Seventh}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Eighth"
      component={Eighth}
    />
    <Stack.Screen name="Ninth" component={Ninth} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Tenth" component={Tenth} />
  </Stack.Group>
</Stack.Navigator>



<stack.navigator initialRouteName={'HomeScreen'}>
   <stack.screen name="HomeScreen" component="HomeScreen"/>
</stack.navigator>



<stack.navigator initialRouteName={'Home'}>
   <stack.screen name="Insurance" component="InsuranceNavigator"/>
   <stack.screen name="Home" component="HomeNavigator"/>
</stack.navigator>
```

EDIT:
go back code in each stack screen

```
const goBack = useCallback(() => {
  navigation.goBack()
}, [navigation])
```

Comment: what you want to create? you can only use one stack.Navigator. Under that stack you can handle everything. why you are doing this?

Comment: @DenysReshetnyk yes I was able to fix this by moving stacks into one stack and grouping them instead